# Dynamic text box that changes depending on date selected on Excel

Tags: excel, date, dynamic-text

I need to create a text box in excel where people can write updates within the text box on the date that they pick (from a list of dates using a data validation list). So if they pick the date 19/01/2024 they can update the text box, but if they change the date to 20/01/2024 the text box is now empty, but when they click back onto 19/01/2024 their update is still there.

Is this possible in Excel?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is very likely that your question gets closed. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. Maybe this link will help you too: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).